# Django Logging Emails not Arriving while other Emails do

Tags: django, gmail

I'm currently using this configuration to receive logging emails from my development as well as my production servers.

```
ADMINS = [('Test1', 'somename@example.com'), ('Test2', 'someothername@example.com')]
SERVER_EMAIL = "correctsender@example.com"
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'include_html': True,
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}
```

The email is then sent with the following configuration for SMTP.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'correctsender@example.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'thepassword' # normally loaded from environment
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'correctsender@example.com'
```

I have enabled "Less secure Apps" in Gmail.

For a few days now, we suspected that error logging was broken. Today we confirmed that the Mails sent via AdminEmailHandler were not arriving, while all other Mails send via the ordinary mail pipeline (no matter if from celery workers or directly from the server) were.

Test with other backends showed that the Mail was sent by django. A quick test with smtplib showed that login was not blocked. How can it be that certain mails are accepted by Gmail while others, only differing in content, are not?

Also, is there a place where rejected Emails are kept in Google (Google Workspace only has a rudimentary report, that doesn't show anything)?

Comment: Can you verify that they are being sent?

Comment: The mails are definitely being sent as changing the backend or using the django shell to send a different mail using the same backend were both successful. It is most definitely google rejecting the django error report for reasons of it being malicious.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is using 2 factors authentification by generating a  [secret key](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6103523?hl=eN) key for the email account and use it in EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD

Comment: I assume you mean app passwords? 
I have now configured that and it still does not work. Same silent failure as with the less secure apps activated.

Answer (score 0):

```
'loggers': {
        'django.request': { **change here to django.db.backend**
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'], c**hange here to console**
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
```

**your logger could look like this and this should fix what you need**

```
    LOGGING = {
        "version": 1,
        "disable_existing_loggers": True,
        "formatters": {
            "verbose": {
                "format": "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s "
                "%(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s"
            }
        },
        "handlers": {
            "console": {
                "level": "DEBUG",
                "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
                "formatter": "verbose",
            }
        },
        "root": {"level": "INFO", "handlers": ["console"]},
        "loggers": {
            "django.db.backends": {
                "level": "ERROR",
                "handlers": ["console"],
                "propagate": False,
            },
            'django.request': { 
                'handlers': ['console'], 
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'propagate': False,
            },
            # Errors logged by the SDK itself if only you wish to monitor with sentry
            "sentry_sdk": {"level": "ERROR", "handlers": ["console"], "propagate": False},
            "django.security.DisallowedHost": {
                "level": "ERROR",
                "handlers": ["console"],
                "propagate": False,
            },
        },
    }
```

this way every log entry passes through the console handler. I hope it works

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: I'm afraid this does not solve the problem of not being able to send _MAIL_ reports

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I "solved" (read commend below) the question by using the [django-gmailapi-backend](https://github.com/dolfim/django-gmailapi-backend). This package can be installed in the following way

1. pip install the package
2. setup a new project in console.cloud.google.com
3. enable the gmail api for your project
4. create OAuth 2.0 credentials

   - choose "Desktop Client"
5. copy client ID and secret into your command line

```
gmail_oauth2 --generate_oauth2_token \
  --client_id="<client_id>" \
  --client_secret="<client_secret>" \
  --scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send"
```

6. open the link the program gives to you
7. authorize the request to use your account
8. copy over the confirmation to the command line
9. retrieve your refresh token and set it as mentioned in the readme of the repo above.
10. you have now set up a more secure app to use as a sending method of your mails.

This only halfway solves the problem of not receiving crash reports. They still won't arrive as the google mailbox considers them to be malicious. However, now, at least the answer of the "non-deliverable"-ness of the message will arrive in the senders inbox enabling you to read the mail that was supposedly malicious. Workaround, yes, but that's the best I could do.

Comment: Btw I will not accept this answer as it is technically not a solution but a workaround. If someone finds a solution feel free to add a new answer.